FunctionInterpolation for 2-dimensional function of difference of variables
Here is a minimal working example:
f = FunctionInterpolation[
  Evaluate[Table[D[Sin[x - y], {{x, y}, k}], {k, 0, 1}]], {x, 0., 
   20.  Pi}, {y, 0., 20.  Pi}]
Plot3D[{f[x, y] - Sin[x - y]}, {x, 0, 20 Pi}, {y, 0, 20 Pi}]

I don't know whether this is a maths problem or MMA problem, but MMA cannot capture the fact that the function is only a function of the difference of two variables. This thing can of course still be redundantly expressed as a function of two variables, so FunctionInterpolation should be able to handle it anyways.
(The actual example has a function which is approximately dependent only on the difference and I do care about the deviance from this behaviour.)

The spacing of points in Table[...] is 1. For function like Sin with a period of 2Pi the resolution is too small. Increase the point density and it will work.
f = FunctionInterpolation[
  Evaluate[Table[D[Sin[x - y], {{x, y}, k}], {k, 0, 1}]], {x, 0, 
   20   Pi, Pi/5}, {y, 0, 20   Pi, Pi/5}]
Plot3D[{f[x, y] - Sin[x - y]}, {x, 0, 20  Pi}, {y, 0, 20  Pi}]



Thanks! Clarify please what you mean "the spacing of points in table is 1". The only table I use explicitly is the one for the derivative. I did not even know MMA used a table in Functioninterpolation, much less 1 as a step size. It should depend on the range specified no?

@DanielHuber Where did you find information concerning increment -option of the grid x,y?

Alternatively, you can also increase the order of derivatives, for example {k, 0, 3}.

@Ulrich Neumann I made a guess and tried it and it worked.

@DanielHuber Very clever!
